# Should Full Outer Joins be avoided in Power Query?

Tags: sql-server, powerquery

I created a full outer join in Power Query that joins 2 views from SQL server, which both run quickly on their own. The query sometimes takes longish (a few minutes) to run, and despite the views being READ UNCOMITTED has blocked other users. Now I need to create another Full outer join, but am nervous about doing so. Also full outer joins in Power Query seem to break query folding - although in this new case that's irrelevant since the join is not to another query/view in SQL server, so it can't be folded anyway.
Should Full Outer Joins in Power Query be avoided?

Comment: It all depends on the situation. You could try running a left join and a right join and then join them with `union`.

Comment: Side note *READ UNCOMITTED* does exactly what is says, it allows a query to read uncommmitted data that's inflight in transactions belonging to other processes (with all the implications of dirty reads, missing rows, duplicated rows etc); it does *not* mean your query does not lock resources.

Comment: Any insights on table schema and how you are doing the join would help people offer better answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: From Microsoft website - 'Transactions running at the READ UNCOMMITTED level do not issue shared locks to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction.' So this very much sounds like it does reduce blocking of data

Comment: I added the second FULL OUTER JOIN and it has caused no issues, so it doesn't look as though there is a fundamental problem with outer joins (although I  have experienced and read that it breaks query folding)  - and the issue is more specific to the particulars of the query I made and our system